# How to create a Custom border shape with round corners in android?

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

The picture demonstrate the actual result I need .
how to crate the borders  with view

```
<View android:layout_width="4dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#72979494" />
```

Which will look like border from all sides

[image]

Comment: Specify which shape exactly you want to achieve

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without custom view, you can have this shape with below XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:weightSum="5">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="#FFFFFF"
                android:layout_weight="2" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="4dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:visibility="visible"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                android:layout_weight="3"
                android:visibility="visible"/>



        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

    </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


    <com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_margin="24dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="24dp"
        app:cardElevation="0dp"
        app:strokeColor="#72979494"
        app:strokeWidth="4dp">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:weightSum="2">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2" />

                <View
                    android:layout_width="4dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:background="#72979494" />


                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_marginEnd="6dp"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:visibility="visible">

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="Your Safety matters"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:textStyle="bold" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
                        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="We've taken actions to keep you safe while using our services"
                        android:textSize="12sp" />
                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>


            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="0dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:weightSum="5">

                <androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="2"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <View
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="4dp"
                        android:background="#72979494" />

                    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:padding="16dp"
                        app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_launcher_background" />

                </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>

                <FrameLayout
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:layout_weight="3">


                    <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
                        android:layout_width="160dp"
                        android:layout_height="40dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="center"
                        android:backgroundTint="#3F51B5"
                        android:text="Read More"
                        android:textAllCaps="false"
                        android:textSize="12sp"
                        app:cornerRadius="20dp" />
                </FrameLayout>

            </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.LinearLayoutCompat>
    </com.google.android.material.card.MaterialCardView>

</FrameLayout>
```

there is a Material Card View and an empty view on top of that to cover an unneeded corner of that.